# Why is the image covering the nav bar

Tags: html, css

I was told to add a fixed nav bar to the code I had made previously.

Here is the CSS for the code. I reviewed it a lot but can't seem to find the issue with it.

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
/*    overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: #c4a1a2;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

.table{
    width: 100%;
/*    height: 00px;*/
}

.table img{
    width: 49.5%;
}

.table td{
    width: 49.5%;
}

#wrapper
{
    width: 99%;
/*  max-width: 1500px;*/
    min-width: 700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
/*  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;*/
} 

.navbar {
/*  

overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

Here's the actual code. I think it's an issue with the container class but I'm not sure. When I commented out the Wrapper ID it was like the nav bar didn't even exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Kayak Spot</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images\RVC-Circles-Logo.jpg">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="container">
          <img src="Images/woman-kayaking.jpg" alt="Kayaking" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="centered">
              <h1>Kayaking, The pastime to calm your nerves.</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="table container">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="Images/sport%20(1).jpg">
                     <div class="centered">
                    <h2>Be it for sport or for leisure, Kayaking is one activity you can't miss.</h2>
          </div>
                </td>
                <td><img src="Images/sport%20(2).jpg"></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a fixed bar at the top of the page, use this piece of code for the navbar class in your css. With this piece of code, your navbar class will be placed at the top of the page.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Better than using a flex display.

If the navbar falls on the rest of the elements, just give the body or #wrapper margin

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 99%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

or

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```